# how to delete the first 2 li elements via jQuery

Tags: jquery, carousel

I am cloning 2 li elements at the end of my list, and after that I would love to delete the first 2. I am trying to achieve an infinite carousel. The way I am doing is:

- wait for 3 seconds
- shift the background
- append a clones of the first 2 items at the end of the ul
- delete the first 2 list elements (I have an issue at this step)
- repeat

here is the
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ekurhzrk/1/) with my attempt, but as mentioned, I can't get to delete the first 2 elements. Any suggestions?

```
  setInterval(function() {
            jQuery('.view').animate({
            left: '-=58'
    });

    jQuery('#first-tt-set').clone().appendTo(".view ul");
    jQuery('#second-tt-set').clone().appendTo(".view ul");
           if($('.view ul li').length == 10){
    jQuery('#first-tt-set:nth-child(1)').remove();
    jQuery('#second-tt-set:nth-child(1)').remove();
    }

   }, 3000);
```

Comment: Issue is that every element gets removed?

Comment: You want delete the first 2 list elements when `ul` have 10 items?

Comment: Exactly @victorlopezsanchez and the issue is that it removes the last 2, regardless if I put first-child or last-child. You can check the behaviour on the developer tools, this is what I think it happens by looking at the variations of the dom

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, modify:

```
<ul>
  <div class="view">
    <ul id="list">
      <li class="tt-set 1"> one </li>
      <li class="tt-set 2"> two </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    <div class="myview">

  </div>
</ul>
```

And your javacript:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {   

  setInterval(function() {
         jQuery('.view').animate({
            left: '-=58'
         });

        jQuery('.tt-set').first().clone().appendTo(".view ul");
        jQuery('.tt-set').first().clone().appendTo(".view ul");
        if($('.view ul li').length == 10){
             $('#list li').first().remove();
             $('#list li').first().remove();
        }

   }, 3000);

});
```